# JDO query returns entity that doesn't match the filter condition

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I ran the following jdo query, it is intended to get a list of entities that has empty "flow id". However, when I check the returned list, it did contain an entity with non-empty flow id.

```
PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManagerProxy();    
String flowId = "";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("flowId", flowId);
List<MyEntity> entities = pm.newQuery(MyEntity.class, " this.flowId == :flowId ").setNamedParameters(params).executeList();
```

It doesn't always happen, but when it happens, I found there is always an update to that entity from another process to clear the "flow id" at a similar time. However, the result I got from the above query have that entity but shows a non-empty flow id. I also checked the JDO object state of the unexpectedly returned entity, it is persistent-clean. The query is run within an active transaction.

Here are the SQL compiled by JDOQLQuery.

```
SELECT 'com.example.MyEntity' AS "NUCLEUS_TYPE","A0"."CREATE_TIME","A0"."DATA_MAX_TIMESTAMP","A0"."DATA_MIN_TIMESTAMP","A0"."ID","A0"."OBSERVATION_ID","A0"."PARTITION_VALUE","A0"."PARTITION_CYCLE","A0"."PARTITION_TIMESTAMP","A0"."FLOW_ID","A0"."PROCESSING_STAGE","A0"."PROCESSING_STATUS","A0"."RECORD_COUNT","A0"."UPDATE_TIME" FROM "MY_ENTITIES" "A0" WHERE "A0"."FLOW_ID" = ?
```

Although I don't think it is relevant, the isolation level is read-committed, the entity is detachable, and that query above is running within a transaction. Please help, thanks!

**Update**

After I change the isolation level to repeatable-read, it never happens again. So highly likely it is related with isolation level. I'm not sure whether there is a bug or not. My data nucleus version is 4.1.6. Any thoughts will help.

Comment: Post the class, and what SQL is actually invoked ?

Comment: Added the sql. @BillyFrost

Comment: And as long as the passed parameter (which you could log) is what you expect then you wont get some invalid object returned.

Comment: The other thing you can do is define a transaction around it, so then you can see when the txn starts and hence connection opens relative to whatever other process is updating.

Comment: That's why I'm asking this question, I logged the parameter, it is an empty string. Once I got the list of result, I immediately check whether there is any entity with non-empty flow_id and I got one. This is all this question is about and I'm asking for clues. The query is already run within an active transaction.  @BillyFrost

Comment: I changed the isolation level from read-committed to repeatable-read, and I haven't seen this issue happen again for a couple hours. If after 24 hours I still can't see that happen, then mostly likely it is related with this. But again, no idea on why.

Comment: A bug in what? DataNucleus simply uses the JDBC driver and gets a connection at the requested isolation. The JDBC driver does the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turn off both level1 and level2 cache. It seems caching in datanucleus doesn't work in some rare cases with multiple processes updating the same row with read-committed isolation level.

When the data store is applying the filtering condition, it can see the latest update from another process (set the flow_id to empty in my example). So it returns that row. However when datanucleus lookup its field using the row id, it checks the cache first but there is a potential stale value in cache for that entity, which seems to be the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Try datanucleus.cache.level2.type=none if you are using concurrent access from different JVMs to your DB.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, what about level1 cache? It seems they are always enabled. @engilyin

Comment: Not sure but from my experience better do not touch level1 if you do not know what are you doing. However if you are using DB from within different JVMs you have to turn off level2 cache. Otherwise one JVM instance will not see changes made recently by another one. 
Did it help to resolve your issue if you turn off the level2 cache?

Comment: Yes, I'm using DB that multiple JVM may update. I didn't set the property you mentioned, but I did set a similar one called "datanucleus.cache.level2.mode" to "none". I was asking about level 1 cache because if there is an issue with multiple JVM, why the existence of level 1 cache doesn't matter? When you say I have to turn off level 2 cache when using multiple JVMs, is there any documentation that I can refer to? @engilyin

Comment: Read here about a cache management in DN: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_2/jdo/persistence.html

Comment: I'm still seeing the similar thing after setting datanucleus.cache.level2.type to none. @engilyin

Comment: Ok. 1) Update the DN to the latest version. 2) How easy to try another DB? E.g. PostgreSQL or hsql? If the bug will disappear it's quite possible some bug in the mysql JDBC driver. If it is bug in DataNucleus you can write the regression test and submit it to DN jira. If you follow the rules of DN and that is the real bug 90% it will be fixed soon.

Comment: After I turn off the level1 cache, the issue disappeared. I think when there is another JVM that updating the datastore, there is a risk that I may have a dirty value in my cache, no matter it is in L1 or L2.